# How do I disable the web camera on my laptop when running Linux Mint 11 & 12?

Tags: linux-mint

I can't locate the settings for my web camera and would like to know how do disable it as well on either Linux Mint 11 and 12

Comment: In the BIOS there's often a setting.

Comment: @sinni800 - Is it not possible to disable the device from within the operating system?

Comment: I don't know Linux much so I can't say. There seem to be possibilities to do so though: http://www.brighthub.com/computing/linux/articles/39252.aspx